# How to move Postgres DB from one Kubernetes cluster to another

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a big (300Gb) Postgres DB running on GKE cluster (Stateful Set, SSD Volume). I need to move this DB to another GKE cluster.

What is the easiest way to accomplish it?

I tried to do it with piping `pg_dump`/`pg_restore`, but it takes forever and for some reason, not all constraints/triggers were recreated.

Is there any proper way to gracefully "shutdown" Postgres server running in Kubernetes and copy the `/pgdata` folder directly (from one volume to another)?

Other ideas?
tnx

Comment: How is the volume that holds the DB data defined?

Comment: Was auto-created using pre-specified ssd `storageClass`

Answer (score 0):

I got few ideas (listed from the most probable to the least) about how you could approach this:

1. Remember to use proper format when using `pg_dump`. Default plain format may not work properly with `pg_restore`. Try to specify different format with `pg_dump` or use `psql -f xxx.tar` instead of `pg_restore`. Remember that it might take a while.
2. You can use a tool to assist you with that. For example [pghoard](https://github.com/aiven/pghoard).
3. You can make a tared backup of you DB and try to copy as a object via Google Cloud Storage.
4. You can try to create PVCs manually, attach pods to those PVCs and than copy your dataset onto those pods.
5. Finally, you may try to create an Init container and use it later for your new cluster.

I suggest starting from point 1 as I think it is the most possible solution. If that would not be enough, try later points from the list.

Please let me know if that helped.